# Hierarchy of Subcategories on Permalink (bug?)

Tags: permalinks

I found out something weird today.

The current permalink is set to `/%category%/%postname%/` but this happens (example):

I have a parent category `Food` and 4 subcategories `Burger`, `Pancake`, `Waffles`, and `Pizza`. As expected, the link should appear like this: `foo.com/food/burger/post-name` but it only works on 2 of my categories and looks like so:

```
foo.com/food/burger/post-name-1
foo.com/food/pancake/post-name-2
foo.com/food/post-name-3
foo.com/food/post-name-4
```

I'm refreshing the permalink settings but it doesn't seem to work.

I've even tried renaming Burger and Pancake to something else, both of them still look fine. But even if I rename Waffles and Pizza to Burger and Pancake, they still don't appear in the permalink.

Any quick solutions for this? Do I have to enter a custom taxonomy thingy?

Comment: Is it possible that Waffles and Pizza(I've got to check your site out when it's done ;D ) don't have the food category set as the parent?

Comment: All of them already have Food as the parent. :-/

Comment: To further narrow down the possibilites: what is the url if you make a new "test" category as a child of "food", then visit a post you put into the test category?

Comment: `Food` still doesn't appear. I think a solution for this is making sure to create all child categories first before adding and setting the parent category. That's based on my feedback on the answer below. Thanks though. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a post belongs to more than one category, regardless of their parent/child structure, WordPress will use the category with the lowest ID in the permalink. If that lower ID belongs to a child category, you'll see the parent/child structure in the permalink.

If you always want parent/child category appearing in the permalink, a simple solution would be to only assign the child category to the post.

Comment: You know what, you gave me the idea on a (dirty, but working) solution I've been longing for. I modified the database table `wp_terms` and just increased the ID of my parent category to a very high 99. Since the IDs of the child categories are now way lower than the parent's, I think they both appear now on the permalink of all posts. Thanks a lot!!!

I'm not sure if it will be helpful to others, but I'll be accepting this anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to first add all your sub categories, then add your parent category. Then you go through the child ones and assign them to the parent!